# Dos Command if exist does not work properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, command, exists

i know its not god to ask ms dos related questions now. but i have a small problem 
i am creating a installer project to a application form that application i need to execute a create database script with a specified path. sql engine returns a error message when the path is not exist therefore i need to check the path is exist if not i need to create the path 
to do that im using the below script for testing but it does not work as i expect. when i execute the same bat file for the second time it gives me below error

"a sub directory or a file \installations\database already exists"

hear is my code

```
c:
IF NOT EXIST c:\installations\database GOTO NODIR
cd C:\installations\database
:NODIR 
mkdir \installations\database\
```

Please help me to resolve this. if i can get an solution from sql it self that will be my answer cz personally i do not prefer dos batches :)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found  a solution for this thank's for helping me out

we can check a folder exist or not by executing below script

```
master.dbo.xp_fileexist @file
```

[Reference](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/30587/)

and we can create a folder using below command

```
SET @Path = 'E:\temp\'
SET @MD =   ' mkdir ' + @Path +'WK' + @wk_no
EXEC    xp_cmdshell @MD, no_output
```

[extracted form](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic604168-8-1.aspx)

Thank you very much for the support for this question. i think this is the ideal solution for my requirement. please feel free to add your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a DOS batch guru but here are a few suggestions :

1. `cd C:\installations\database` this seems really wrong. What about :

   ```
   C:
   cd installations\database
   ```
2. Again, why don't you verify you are in the correct directory first :

   ```
   :NODIR
   C:
   mkdir installations
   cd installations
   mkdir database
   ```

Comment: i did try this but it didnt work

thing is if the folder does not exist in the specified location script will create one but if the folder exists it gives me an error message

Answer (score 0):

Your original code had faulty logic.

It was only changing the directory if the directory already existed, then it was falling into the code to create the directory.

When checking if a directory exists, it is best to append `\` to the end to make sure IF EXIST matches only a directory and not a file name.

Here is corrected logic.

```
c:
if not exist "c:\installations\database\" mkdir "c:\installations\database"
cd "c:\installations\database"
```